# How do i disable docs for a storybook page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am using storybook to document the components i am developing. I am using Docs addons to document the components. The issue i am facing is that i have some pages for which i do not want the docs to show up i.e a get started. Consider following screenshot:

[image]

As seen in the image get start page has show code button at bottom right and there is also a border. I do not want these to appear for this page. How can i disable it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new CSF format, you can disable docs for a specific story by:

```
export const foo = () => <Button>foo</Button>;
foo.parameters = { docs: { disable: true } };
```

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/addons/docs/docs/recipes.md#disabling-docs-stories